# What are these components around the CPU socket?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power, processor-socket

Right next to the CPU socket, on the left and the top, you can first see a row of silver caps  and behind these are little dark grey "boxes". What are those components and why do they get super hot?
I believe they have something to do with CPU power. Maybe inductors? I figured, that many mainboards have these components visible next to the socket.

[image: Mainboard]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Voltage regulator modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator_module) - they step down the 12v that goes into the CPU power supply to the lower voltages that the CPU uses. They're often covered by heatsinks, as they do generate quite a bit of heat.

Comment: I admit I was wondering if they could be the SMPS switching inductors but I've never seen that many channels all working simultaneously and I don't think you can have multiple inductors on one "channel". In that case it would be a large number of channels and I believe they would all be individually supplied by power, blocked by FETS and would also have to be synchronised to ensure they are all "on" at the same time so none get overloaded. My experience is with stuff far less greedy than modern CPUs though so I could be wrong, and this is a reasonable alternative.

Comment: Yup - a lot of modern CPUs have a ridiculous number of VRMs. I I always assumed the big blocks were mosfets but I guess they could be https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-vrm/  A Z490's a high end motherboard so would need to support fairly high wattage CPUs

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Now that I heard voltage regulator modules, it clicked. I've heard of VRMs once before. So I started researching those and found exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Another question, do I have to cool them? - Does it benefit the lifespan of the parts? I mean, is it worth the thermal pads and heatsinks?

Comment: I'd assume if the designers felt they needed it, they would have added it. I'd say no, the system cooling would be good enough, though some components have heatsinks for em.

Comment: Hey, everyone. Now, almost a year ago, I've started studying computer science including computer system architecture. These are indeed VRMs, well parts of them. The black boxes are inductors which are called "high-power chokes" they are used alongside MOSFETs and Caps to regulate the CPU input voltage. As @JourneymanGeek pointed out, modern mainboards use ridiculous amounts of these, since modern CPUs can draw up to 310W of power when overclocked (looking at you, 13900K, lol)